# XSL-FO: Border made of asterisks

Tags: border, xsl-fo

In XSL-FO, it is possible to make a fo:block have a border that can be solid or dashed, etc. Is it possible to make border that consists of asterisks (*)?

```
*****************
*               *
*  some text    *
*               *
*****************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always done this with SVG images as backgrounds. You could vary the images evens for the corners, sides, top and bottom. Basically put down a table for the borders with one center cell and then inside the middle cell, whatever you wish. If your pattern may get cut off, you might need to adjust the inner cell a bit. Like this:

```
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1pt"/>
                <fo:table-column/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1pt"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <!-- Put background behind this top row -->
                    <fo:table-row background-image="diamond.svg"
                        rx:background-content-height="scale-to-fit" background-repeat="repeat-x">
                        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3">
                            <fo:block line-height="1pt">
                                <fo:leader/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <!-- Put backround behind this left cell -->
                        <fo:table-cell background-image="diamond.svg"
                            rx:background-content-width="scale-to-fit"
                            background-repeat="repeat-y">
                            <fo:block>
                                <fo:leader/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <!-- Tweak height here -->
                            <fo:block-container margin-top="0.4pt" margin-bottom="0.4pt">
                                <fo:table text-align="center">
                                    <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>
                                    <fo:table-body>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                                            <fo:block margin="18pt"> Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here. Put
                                            all your content in here. Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here. Put
                                            all your content in here. Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here. Put
                                            all your content in here. Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here. Put
                                            all your content in here. Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here. Put
                                            all your content in here. Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here. Put
                                            all your content in here. Put all your content in
                                            here. Put all your content in here. Put all your
                                            content in here. Put all your content in here.
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </fo:table-body>
                                </fo:table>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <!-- Put backround behind this right cell -->
                        <fo:table-cell background-image="diamond.svg"
                            rx:background-content-width="scale-to-fit"
                            background-repeat="repeat-y">
                            <fo:block>
                                <fo:leader/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <!-- Put background behind this bottom row -->
                    <fo:table-row background-image="diamond.svg"
                        rx:background-content-height="scale-to-fit" background-repeat="repeat-x">
                        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3">
                            <fo:block line-height="1pt">
                                <fo:leader/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
```

Yielding something like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Apache FOP, which does not support rx: extensions. Is there a way to do it with FOP?

Comment: You probably do not need it if you scale the SVG appropriately for the size of your border. Or you can use the FOP extension to scale the height (not content height).